# Versatile ASP.NET CMS in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system

We are making a public website on ASP.NET and we are looking for a really **versatile CMS** that will give us enough **freedom** and allow us to create not only standard content pages (a feature which all CMS offer), but also pages with **custom ASP.NET programming**.

Imagine the following case: our site will contain several custom ASP.NET pages programmed in C# which allow the visitors to view and search for some financial products (the site will actually be devoted to structured financial products in Russia). Those **pages** will be programmed **in pure ASP.NET / C#**.

At the same time, we will have lots of **content pages** (with simple text, images, etc., but without any programming), and we would like to be able to add those pages to the site using a web interface like in most CMS systems.

The **problem** is that **most CMS systems** like DotNetNuke make it very **difficult** to add **custom ASP.NET pages** to the site. In DDN, one has to create special DNN modules, and there this requires lots of additional efforts.

**My question**: is there any lightweight, versatile CMS system that lets users manage simple content pages and at the same time create custom ASP.NET pages? Maybe what we require is **not a classic CMS**, but rather a set of components that can help us manage simple content pages?

Thank you.

---

Thank you for your answers.

I am wondering whether using a CMS is the only way of solving our problem? Maybe there are **ASP.NET controls** that allow to **manage pages in a CMS-like way**? So we ideally would like something very lightweight.

Comment: What CMS features do you need?

Comment: The main feature is the ability for administrators (not programmers) to add pages to the site and edit menus - and do all that using a web interface.

Programmers must have the possibility to add custom ASP.NET pages to the site - easily, without the need to create modules like in DotNetNuke.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for open source/free solutions so the public facing licensing costs may be a bit high (otherwise i would have put this in answers) but Sharepoint will provide a simple content management system that will let you create and deploy cusotm asp.net pages.

Comment: micha12, could you please tell me which cms have you selected for your project. I'm asking because I have same choice to do for the project I'm working on.

Answer (score 7):

Umbraco - http://umbraco.org

Written entirely in C#, free, small footprint, uses master pages and very flexible.

Custom .NET can be added via Macros (.NET user controls) or complete ASPX pages, provided you specify in the web.config that the file exists and Umbraco doesn't try to find it in the content database.

Comment: Umbraco owns most Enterprise CMS's on the market, 
Now days it has a long list of website using it. 
Wired Mag, Peugeot, Microsoft, Heinz, Suzuki

Answer (score 7):

[N2](http://n2cms.com/) is a free open source ASP.NET CMS with support also for MVC. It's opinionated, uses .Net classes for the programming model and is very open and extensible.

Comment: Did you use it? Does it allow to add custom ASP.NET pages without hassles?

Comment: You have complete freedom in creating pages. The "N2" in my answer is a link to the N2 site, though it's maybe no clear. There are plenty of screenshots and a clear description of feature, plus a live demo where you can change pages etc.

Comment: How does it compare to Umbraco?

Comment: Don't know - never used Umbraco, sorry. Like I said, have a good read through the N2 web site - it should answer your questions. Also, it's open source so you can just download it and try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Cuyahoga](http://www.cuyahoga-project.org/) as well. Here's the [feature list](http://www.cuyahoga-project.org/home/features.aspx). It has a WYSIWYG content manager

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe I would say that you need a development platform and a CMS in one. Take a look at [Sitefinity](http://www.sitefinity.com), I would say that what you are looking for is exactly its main advantage. It makes custom development a piece of cake.

**Disclaimer:** I am on the team developing Sitefinity at [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com).

Comment: It looks as if Sitefinity is not free and costs about $900...

Comment: It has a Community edition, which is free. The missing functionality is something you would need in an enterprise-level CMS. http://www.sitefinity.com/product/compare-editions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Two open source CMS systems written in .NET that you may want to evaluate are:

1) [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/)

and

2) [Oxite](http://www.codeplex.com/oxite) from Microsoft (emphasis on blogging)

Comment: DotNetNuke is not versatile enough - one cannot add a custom ASP.NET page and is required to create DNN modules. Oxite runs on ASP.NET MVC - we are using WebForms, not MVC - so Oxite is not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Kentico CMS](http://kentico.com). It is not free but very powerful. YOu can add your custom code to your pages/templates as you can see here:

devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/adding_custom_code_to_the_aspx_page_template.htm

Answer (score 0):

When you dont care to much about workflow and other premium CMS stuff, but like to have an inline HTML editor and care a lot about programming your application.... take a look at SmallCMS. It is free, open source, lightweight and a good starting point.

[smallcms.codeplex.com](http://smallcms.codeplex.com/)

Comment: website works now.  it was smallcms.net, so I'm assuming they changed their website domain.  If the change isn't visible yet, smallcms.codeplex.com is the new site.

Answer (score 0):

Webnodes CMS allows you to do what you want. You have full control over everything. It's more of a CMS framework than an out-of-the-box CMS. Templates are regular aspx pages, without any restrictions. See more at [www.webnodes.com](http://www.webnodes.com)